# Auth Header is empty

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using MSAL to get an auth token and trying to pass it to another function to make a call to an azure api, whenever I try to use the token in the second function I get a 401 with the error "AuthenticationFailedMissingToken"

Here is the code:

```
export class integrationAccountService
{
  authToken: string;

  constructor( private authService: MsalService, private httpclient: HttpClient, private api: ApiService) {
    this.authToken = "";
  }

  gettoken() {
    this.authService.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest).then(tokenResponse => {
      this.authToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
      //console.log(this.authToken);
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  getcertificates(): Observable<Certificate> {
    const httpOptions : Object = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authToken,
      }),
      responseType: 'json'
    };
    return this.httpclient.get<Certificate>(environment.api.getAllCertificatesUrl, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

I thought this.authToken would be reachable in another function in the same class, any clarification would be helpful

Comment: It generally is. But are you executing (and awaiting the result) `gettoken` before you call `getCertificates`. Furthermore "Authorization header is missing" is not a default error result. Are you sure your API expects that header in exactly that form. Have you tried inspecting your network requests in the developer tools of the browser if the request contains the `Authorization` header with the correct value?

Comment: Thanks for the input @derpirscher. To clarify the request retrurns 401 with the code "AuthenticationFailedMissingToken". The request works if I hard code the token in the authorization header, but when I use this.auth token the header is 'Bearer '

Comment: Again the question: Did you execute `gettoken` and did it return sucessfully before you called `getCertificate` ?

Comment: Sorry, yes gettoken does sucessfully return a token.

Comment: If that's the case, the error is not in the posted code. Because if `gettoken` successfully set `this.authToken` before `getcertificates` is called, `getcertificates` will of course have access to `this.authToken`.  So either there is a timing issue or something else resets the `authToken` property

Comment: And I'm not particular familiar with angular, but I suppose the runtime takes care that there are not multiple instances of the same service? Because if that was the case, one instance might have a perfectly valid authToken, while the other instance of the same service still has an empty token ...

Comment: Thanks for the help, the problem must be in my component where I am calling the functions, working through it now. It could be that I am trying to use multiple instances of the same service as you pointed out

Comment: Have a look at the docs https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services